# How to set a range of Assertion in Cypress while trying to get the value from the CSS

Tags: cypress, chai, assertion, should.js

This is my code:

```js
try {   
    cy.get('.hello-bar-contentwrap')
        .should('have.css','padding-top','28px')
        .should('have.css','padding-right','37px')
        .should('have.css','padding-left','37px') }
```

What I Intend to achieve is that CSS - Padding bottom should check for a range for ex. From 18px to 21px so that I can pass the case which is as failed below:

Something like this:

`.should('have.css','height', expect('48px').to.be.closeTo('47','49'))`

**Issue screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Did you get the workaround for the same ? I want to do a similar thing

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [chaijs closeTo](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_closeto) the parameters are numbers, so a little conversion will work

```js
const cssText = '48px'
const numericHeight = +cssText.replace('px', '')
expect(numericHeight).to.be.closeTo(47, 2)      // 2nd param is +/-, not absolute
```

Specifically your test,

```js
.should('have.css', 'height')
.then(height => +height.replace('px', ''))  // convert
.should('be.closeTo', 47, 2)
```

This must be the last in the chain, as the subject changes from element to height attribute.